# Stream Video from Mobile

Tags: mobile, video-streaming, rtsp, rtmp

I'm looking the best solution for **video streaming from Mobile devices**.

As far as I understand, The most efficient way is using RTMP \ RTSP \ UDP protocol,
or TCP \ websockets.

So far I've found few options:

- [HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH1-SW1) (IOS) - but it's only for IOS
- [HTML5 LIVE VIDEO STREAMING VIA WEBSOCKETS](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets) - which works on node.js, but with no audio!
- [BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/) - bidrectional realtime binary data with binary websockets (also websockets on Node.js)
- [WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) - for client side

The thing is - I don't really know how to work it out on different kinds of mobile devices, or what protocols are best to used (and the least work to do... :)

Any suggestions \ ideas \ comments ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's depend upon your platform,Any way my suggestions

Desktop(win/mac/linux)-WebRTC is best,Because its peer to peer communication means browser to browser hd video chat not only video.And also Audio,file,etc main feature is without plugin no need to install any plugin(Note:its support chrome,opera,firefox only)

Android:WebRTC
IOS:BinaryJS is good option

Answer (score 1):

There is an iOS library I can recommend. It can stream through RTMP from mobile devices and you can use HLS for downlink playback. It's called the [**ANGL library**](http://angl.tv/rtmp-live-streaming-library), and it can be used for streaming live content to a media server like Wowza, which then can broadcast the stream in a multitude of formats.