# Live Streaming from mobile with Unity3D

Tags: android, ios, mobile, unity-game-engine, live-streaming

I want to stream the viewport of my mobile App to another mobile / PC app using Unity.

By now Im able to capture the viewport

```
tex.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
```

Scale it, encode to PNG and send over the net using PhotonEngine

```
TextureScaler.scale (tex, w,h);
byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG ();
```

With this approach im able to send the viewport over the net to any platform (ios,android,mac,windows) with any combination of client-server platform.

But I cant reach a good frame rate with a good quality.

I have check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728560/stream-video-from-mobile) and [this](http://ngmsvid.com/ngmstrans.php) but I have no idea on how to integrate that with unity3D.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you on advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: AFAIK, The reason you're getting low FPS is because the `Texture.ReadPixels` and `Texture.Apply` (It gets called in `TextureScaler` IIRC). These operations are heavy because you're uploading new texture information to the GPU. My work with this has led me to the inevitable.. make a native plugin.

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios Than you for comment. So, I need to implement a native plugin that do the Texture.ReadPixels  and Texture.Apply work right?
You mean C code for android with JNI? Or can I do it on java? I will start reading about the issue but if you can recommend me a starting point will be great. Im a bit lost. Thank you in advance!!